# Where to add a capacitor

Tags: led, transistors, capacitor, speakers

So I have a small circuit that I made to flash some led's in sync with my music. It's just a signal from my speaker going into the base of my 2N3903 transistor and the ground of the led is being interrupted by the transistor. The circuit works just fine but I was wondering, how and where can I add a capacitor in this circuit to make the lights dim off instead of shut off imeaditly.

Thank you!

Comment: I have not tried that yet, I drew up the circuit on a pice of graph paper and took a picture of it and was going to add it but I can't seem to find out how to do that on my phone. Currently not actually near my pc.

Answer (score 1):

Well a schematic would be pretty helpful to get you a better answer but have you tried just putting a 10uF capacitor in parallel with the LED?  Better yet maybe with a small current limiting series resistor between the positive side of the cap and the diode.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to put an electrolytic capacitor in between one of the LEDs leads and what it connects to, but probably not both leads. I say an electrolytic capacitor because they usually have higher capacitance, thus a good enough dim time (as opposed to a few millisecond dim time)